# search query of Gerrit for multiple users and in open state

Tags: gerrit

I am trying to pull all the open CRs which are waiting for the review for a list of users using the below Gerrit query I am unable to get the list of the open CRs for all the users mentioned below, please help me get the correct query

`status:open owner:rajesh@abc.com,ramesh@abc.com,kumar@abc.com`

Please help me in getting the correct format of the query so that I can pull the open CRs which are waiting for review for multiple users.

Comment: Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example?* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following query:

```
status:open AND (owner:rajesh@abc.com OR owner:ramesh@abc.com OR owner:kumar@abc.com)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Marcelo Avila for your quick reply , it worked fine.